# Force a developer to implement a fragment callback

Tags: android, android-fragments, callback

Hi I have an issue where my coworkers frequently forget to implement the callback to my widely used generic internet error fragment. I have the issue where we only find out a class is missing it when we evoke the fragment. I.E. the application mysteriously crashes and we waste time looking up why.

Short of implementing [custom lint for android](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/building-custom-lint-checks-in-android/) how can I force a developer to implement the callback? This is a simple fragment that just shows text and takes no arguments.

```
 @Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    try {
        mNoInternetCallbackInterface = (NoInternetCallbackInterface) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}



@Override
public void onStart(){
    super.onStart();
    try {
        mNoInternetCallbackInterface = (NoInternetCallbackInterface) getActivity();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(getActivity().toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mNoInternetCallbackInterface = null;
}
```

Evoked here in the activity. (yes I know I should use a create instance function instead, but wont solve this issue)

```
        @Override
        public void onError(final Throwable e) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            NoInternetDialogFragment mNoInternetDialogFragment = new NoInternetDialogFragment();
            try {
                mNoInternetDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "no_internet");
            } catch (IllegalStateException ie) {
                // ignore as this code is going away.
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 3):

You could put anything that's necessary in a parent fragment, and make other fragments extend parent fragment.We can add abstract method to force user to implement it.

```
abstract public class ParentFragment extends Fragment {
    //put anything needs to be inherited in this class

    public void onError(final Throwable e) {
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        NoInternetDialogFragment noInternetDialogFragment = new NoInternetDialogFragment();
        try {
            mNoInternetDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, "no_internet");
            onErrorHandle(fragmentManager, noInternetDialogFragment);
        } catch (IllegalStateException ie) {
            // ignore as this code is going away.
        }

    }
    abstract protect void onErrorHandle(FragmentManager e, NoInternetDialogFragment fragment);
}
```

Here's child fragment:

```
public class ChildFragment extends ParentFragment {

     void onErrorHandle(FragmentManager e, NoInternetDialogFragment fragment) {//your code}
}
```

So it's ParentFragment that'll handle the case.

Comment: @StarWind I edited the answer. Please let me know is that what you need.

Comment: I think the confusion here is that you answered about inheritance. I am calling this with an Activity so we cannot just inherit / override.

Comment: make parent abstract and add add abstract protect method to force user implement it.

Comment: @StarWind I think that the new version answer is what you want.